# Why does Windows 10 take so long to empty the recycle bin

Tags: windows-10, recycle-bin

I just recently upgraded my system and my new motherboard only has drivers for Windows 10 so I had to upgrade my OS at the same time from Window 7 Pro 64bit to Windows 10 Pro 64bit (1809).

While restoring my files to the new system I discovered that the recycle bin in Windows 10 takes an inordinate amount of time to empty compared to Windows 7, which I was able to empty the recycle bin of hundreds of files totaling 2-3 gigs in a matter of seconds (10 max), but with Windows 10 even a much smaller amount of files (less than 200) with a combined size of around 150mb takes anywhere between 15-30 seconds to complete and seems to hang at the start of the process for a few seconds before finally staring to remove the files.

I am not sure if this matters at all but my CPU in the new system is about 3x faster than my one in my old system and I went from DDR3 to DDR4 ram which again is faster so I am sure that's not the bottleneck.

The actual drive that I use in the new system is a M.2 SSD and is the same one my I used in my old system so that should not be a factor either yet I am having this issue and no idea why so I hope someone might be able to shed some light on situation and offer a possible fix.

I have attach a screenshot of a summary of my system specs as well as the properties of the recycle bin in the hope that it will be of some use when helping me with this issue.

[System Specs & Recycle Bin Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdvl4.jpg)

Comment: Can you confirm the recycle bin is set to the SSD and not some other disk?  Please edit your question to include this vital information necessary to answer your question.

Comment: I updated the question with the info you requested